# Reference request: books on self-rescue while climbing

Tags: safety, rock-climbing, climbing, self-rescue

Can people recommend books or online resources on self-rescue for roped climbing? As a beginning trad leader, I think I should have a basic understanding of topics like how to escape a belay and how to rappel with an injured person. I have the book by Fasulo, and I'm finding it difficult to understand. The book presents lots and lots of complicated setups and scenarios, including lots of information that seems mainly relevant to aid climbing, which I don't do (although I realize that aid-climbing techniques could become necessary for self-rescue when something goes wrong while free-climbing). I would prefer more of a "dummy's guide to self-rescue." I will probably also pay for professional instruction on this, but I don't think I'll retain much from a day of instruction unless I prepare by studying up on the topic as much as possible.

Comment: Since answers are supposed to be in English, I'll leave this as a comment. If you happen to know Spanish, I recommend this great book - ISBN: 9788487746918 (title translates to: Prevention, Security, and Self-rescue).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Climbing Self Rescue: Improvising Solutions for Serious Situations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/089886772X)

[image]

This book presents self-rescue techniques in the first section. The latter half contains several dozen "what would you do" scenarios, allowing you to test what you've learned. It gives one or more solutions to each scenario, as well as highlighting things to watch out for. Most importantly, it lists ways to prevent the scenario from arising in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

[Libby peters' book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rock-Climbing-Essential-Skills-Techniques/dp/0954151119) is good and covers self rescue in detail.

[image]

It's also the offical book for the UK Mountain Leader and single Pitch award qualifications

There is a series on self rescue which I saw recently [on UKClimbing.com](http://www.ukclimbing.com/articles/page.php?id=3472), could be worth a watch